# how to access a gui object in a nested function from a base workspace

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I think my issue is I don't know how to access `guiel.hAX(3)` property in my button callback function where I put `kiddies = get(guiel.hAX(3),'Children');`
I got the error:

```
Undefined variable "guiel" or class "guiel.hAX".

Error in showTF/callback_update_model (line 508)
    kiddies = get(guiel.hAX(3),'Children');
```

My nested function for button callback:

```
function callback_update_model(~,~)
    vars.dropheight = str2num(get(edit(2),'String'));
    vars.armradius = str2num(get(edit(1),'String'));
    kiddies = get(guiel.hAX(3),'Children');
    delete(kiddies); 
    clear kiddies;
    set(guiel.tfPanel,'Visible','off','Position',cnst.tfPanelpos);
    set(guiel.hAX(1),'Position',cnst.axpos1);

    if ishandle(guiel.hAX(2)) 
    set(guiel.hAX(2),'Position',cnst.axpos2);
    end
    eval(get(guiel.hPB(4),'Callback'));
end
```

I initialize variables in other mfile

```
guiel.hAX(1) = -1;
guiel.hAX(2) = -1;
guiel.hAX(3) = -1;
guiel.tfPanel = -1;
...
    guiel.hAX(3) = axes('Parent',guiel.tfPanel,'Color',cnst.OFFWHITE,'Layer',...
                'top','Xlim',[0 1],'YLim',[0 1],'GridLineStyle','none','Units','Normalized',...
                'XTick',[],'YTick',[],'Box','off','Visible','off','Position',cnst.axpos3);
```

Comment: Please see [mcve].

Comment: You have to store your guiel variable in the GUI data. Here is more info on how to [Store or retrieve UI data](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).

Comment: @Zep Could you give me an example for the change? Thanks!

Comment: Can I use EVALIN function to access the data from base workspace within the function?  I am not sure if this works for my case.

Comment: @DavidLing I could do that if you posted a Minimal, [Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as suggested above

Answer (score 1):

To make data available in callbacks, you can store the data in the UserData property of the figure.  If your figure handle is h_fig, then you would use code like this to store the data in the figure:

```
set(h_fig, 'UserData', guiel)
```

In your callback, you can use the gcbo function to get the handle to the figure, then extract the user data, use code like this:

```
[~, h_fig] = gcbo;
guiel = get(h_fig, 'UserData')
```